# Simple Form Radio Button with Text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textbox, radio-button, simple-form

I am learning to use the `simple_form` gem to achieve several things but am uncertain how I could do it. Below is how the outcome would be.

**Update:**
I would like to have a radio/checkbox button with text and input field

- Foo ________ **(radio)**(placeholder: "Type here")
- ________ **(radio)**(placeholder: "Type here")
- Bar2
- Foo ________ **(checkbox)**
- ________ **(checkbox)**

Codes I could write so far

```
f.radio_button :name, "Foo"
```

Could anyone guide me how to create the form using `simple_form` gem?

Comment: `form_for @user do |f|
  f.collection_radio_buttons :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
end` [HERE](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-radio-buttons) is the documentation

Comment: What about a radio button with text and input field? Example as listed above: `Foo ________`